# Can't figure out how to get ffmpeg to save to an odd file extension

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a network encoder for SageTV.  I get request from the SageTV with certain filenames.  I'm trying to capture video from my capture card and write out to a file called

> 'D:\Media\tvrecordings\RokuNetworkEncoderonlocalhost4510TVTuner-
>   0.mpgbuf'

Here's the command I'm using:

> C:\Users\User>C:/Users/User/Desktop/ffmpeg-20150928-git-235381e-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe
>   -f dshow  -crossbar_video_input_pin_number 2  -i video="ATI AVStream Analog Capture"
>   D:\Media\tvrecordings\RokuNetworkEncoderonlocalhost4510TVTuner-0.mpgbuf

When I run that command, I get this error:

```
[NULL @ 00000000087f9160] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'D:\Media\
tvrecordings\RokuNetworkEncoderonlocalhost4510TVTuner-0.mpgbuf'
D:\Media\tvrecordings\RokuNetworkEncoderonlocalhost4510TVTuner-0.mpgbuf: Invalid
 argument
```

But if I change .mpgbuf to .mpg it works fine  .  I am forced to use that filename though.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: That's what I needed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general your file extension gives FFmpeg a "hint" as to what container format you want.  If it's not the right one or you want to explicitly specify one (or you can't use one, in your case) then you can manually call one out like.

```
 ffmpeg -i XXX -f mpegts outfile
```